# closed rectangle of content zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How can I prove that set of the form $$[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\times...\times[a_n,b_n]$$
is not a content-zero set, where $a_i<b_i\forall 1\leq i\leq n$.

**What I tried**

I know the proof for $n=1$ case, I tried to mimic the proof for general $n$. But that seems difficult. I also tried to get a contradiction to the fact that content of 1 closed interval is not zero, but all in vain. Please help.

Comment: are you allowed to use that  the volume of this rectangle is $(b_1-a_1)....(b_n-a_n)$?

Comment: @MariosGretsas, yeah.

Comment: I was thinking of an approach to prove that if we have a set which is a union of segments, this set is the union of uninterested segments with total volume less or equal than total volume of initial segments (not sure how easy to prove that). If we cover initial segment with finite number of intersected segments, we can use measure and finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

> $\textbf{Lemma}$ If $P,P_1,...,P_m$ are open-closed rectangles and if $P \subseteq P_1 \cup...\cup P_m$,then $vol(P) \leq vol(P_1)+...+vol(P_m)$

A proof for this lemma can be found here:

http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~papadim/measure_theory.pdf  in page 41.

The same equality is true if  we use open rectangles instead of open-closed.

Assume that the rectangle,denoted by $A$ has content zero.

Then for for $\epsilon=\frac{(b_1-a_1)...(b_n-a_n)}{2}$

exist rectangles $J_1,...J_m$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^mJ_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^m vol(J_n)<\epsilon$

But $2\epsilon=Vol(A) \leq \sum_{n=1}^m vol(J_n)<\epsilon$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: How would you show the last step, that $vol(A)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n vol(J_n)$?

Comment: @Martund i edited..